# Как получить некоторую информацию со страницы и отобразить ее в приложении Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, html, .net, winforms

Требуется взять со страницы некоторую информацию и отобразить у себя в приложении. Был использован элемент WebBrowser, который загружает всю страницу. Как теперь оттуда запрашивать отдельные элементы?

Comment: http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=43360 - должно помочь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

используйте Html Agility Pack —это удобный .NET парсер HTML
http://html-agility-pack.net